# Writing a basic XOR neural network program

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, xor

I am trying to write a neural network that recognizes the xor function from scratch. The full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/Xm6hWsfR)  (in python 3).

I am currently getting the error :

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients
```

I am new to tensorflow and I don't understand why this is. Can anyone help me out in correcting my code? Thanks in advance.

P.S. If more details are required in the question, do let me know before downvoting. Thanks again!

Edit: relevant part of code:

```
def initialize_parameters():
    # Create Weights and Biases for Hidden Layer and Output Layer
    W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", [2, 2], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", [2, 1], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
    W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", [1, 2], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    b2 = tf.get_variable("b2", [1, 1], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
    parameters = {
            "W1" : W1,
            "b1" : b1,
            "W2" : W2,
            "b2" : b2
    }
    return parameters

def forward_propogation(X, parameters):

    threshold = tf.constant(0.5, name = "threshold")
    W1, b1 = parameters["W1"], parameters["b1"]
    W2, b2 = parameters["W2"], parameters["b2"]

    Z1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W1, X), b1)
    A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1)
    tf.squeeze(A1)
    Z2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W2, A1), b2)
    A2 = tf.round(tf.sigmoid(Z2))
    print(A2.shape)
    tf.squeeze(A2)
    A2 = tf.reshape(A2, [1, 1])
    print(A2.shape)
    return A2

def compute_cost(A, Y):

    logits = tf.transpose(A)
    labels = tf.transpose(Y)
    cost = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits, labels = labels)
    return cost

def model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, learning_rate = 0.0001, num_epochs = 1500):

    ops.reset_default_graph()
    (n_x, m) = X_train.shape
    n_y = Y_train.shape[0]
    costs = []
    X, Y = create_placeholders(n_x, n_y)
    parameters = initialize_parameters()
    A2 = forward_propogation(X, parameters)
    cost = compute_cost(A2, Y)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    with tf.Session() as session:
        session.run(init)
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            epoch_cost = 0
            _, epoch_cost = session.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {X : X_train, Y : Y_train})
        parameters = session.run(parameters)
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(A2), tf.argmax(Y))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
        print("Training Accuracy is {0} %...".format(accuracy.eval({X : X_train, Y : Y_train})))
        print("Test Accuracy is {0} %...".format(accuracy.eval({X : X_test, Y : Y_test})))
    return parameters
```

Comment: Kindly include relevant part of the code here itself rather than linking the whole code to an external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the use of `tf.round` when you define `A2` ([known issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5888), by the way).

In this particular task, the solution is simply not to use `tf.round` at all. Remember that, the output of `tf.sigmoid` is the value between `0` and `1`, which can be interpreted as probability of result `1`. Cross-entropy loss function is measuring the distance to the target, `0` or `1`, and computes the needed update to the weights based on this distance. Calling `tf.round` before the cross-entropy will squeeze the probability to either `0` or `1` - that's will make cross-entropy pretty meaningless.

By the way, [`tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy) should work better, because you've applied the sigmoid yourself in the second layer.

Comment: Thanks. it's working now, but giving an accuracy of 1.0% :/ Could you help me improve it? I'll mark the answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update the code in question so that it could be reproduced?